# In LightGBM, what does Max_depth = -1 (no limit) means?

Tags: max, depth, hyperparameters, lightgbm

what does no limitation mean when tuning the parameter `max_depth` in LightGBM?
does every tree have different depth ? 
is there a way to check what is the trained model depth?

Answer (score 0):

From the LightGBM documetation:
max_depth (int, optional (default=-1)) – Maximum tree depth for base learners, <=0 means no limit.

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html